# Python BeautifulSoup4 Web Scraping Multiple Pages on one Web Site

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, expression

I need a specific answer on how to actually iterate and parse through multiple pages on a website , where the URL is known but just to an extent.
I have looked through many tutorials but none tells me actually how to get to the next page - maybe I need to use a regular expression.
I would like to know if anyone can just give me some advice or start on where to look for this:
As such I will give you an example - let us use the Python Website for instance - we know them all very well: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/
On this page you will see that there is the "next" button that continues the page to : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appetite.html
From there on if you click the "next" button only the last /*.html changes.

What I would like to have advice on is how to actually go through all the last /*.html iterations and catch those html pages.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `href` values are all relative to the current URL, you cannot simply check if `href` attribute starts with `https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/`. Note that these links have the `reference` and `internal` classes, let's use that:

```
soup.find_all("a", class_=["reference", "internal"])
soup.select("a.reference.internal")  # CSS selector to check multiple classes
```

Here is an example working code that extracts the `href` values for the page:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


base_url = "https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/"
response = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

for link in soup.select("a.reference.internal"):
    url = link["href"]
    absolute_url = urljoin(base_url, url)

    print(url, absolute_url)
```

Note that we have to use [`.urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) to get the absolute URLs so that we can follow them.

Comment: Look at the page, the `href` attributes are all relative. They look like `appetite.html` not `https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appetite.html`

Comment: I just noticed that this grabs EVERY link - including links that are anchors for the same page. Take a peek at my answer and lemme know what you thinK?

Comment: @wilbur I think your answer is much closer to what AP was actually planning to do. Thanks.

Comment: Wahoo! Gettin some props from alecxe, it's a dream come true.

Answer (score 1):

alecxe's answer is good and was essentially going to be the second half to this answer, but it duplicates pages. For example, the urls `https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html` and `https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting` are actually the same page, the second is just an anchor on the page.

If you want to do this like you initially stated - find the value of the "next" link's href and then navigate there - you can do something like this:

Use regex to find the `div`s with "next" in them, and then use their parents to get the actual href. Use [`urljoin()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) to join together the base_url and the href together to get the absolute url of the next page.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urljoin


BASE_URL = "https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/"

def get_next_url(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    selected = soup.select('div.related h3')
    nav = selected[-1] if selected else None# grab the last one with this css selector
    if nav:
        href = nav.parent.find('a', text=re.compile('next'))['href']
        new_url = urljoin(BASE_URL, href)
        return new_url
    else:
        return None

next = get_next_url(BASE_URL)
while next:
    old = next
    next = get_next_url(old)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version of the function that recursively searches for pages of Python tutorial. It's shorter and I think even more clear.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

base_url = 'https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/'

def find_pages(url):
    """Loop over all pages in online Python tutorial."""
    # try open url
    try:
        page = urlopen(url).read()
    # quit if there's no Next link
    except HTTPError:
        print("The end!")
        return

    # parse the page
    soup = bs(page, 'html.parser')

    # find all occurences of the links, that contain text 'next' and have no attributes
    next_url = soup.findAll('a', text = "next", attrs = {'accesskey' : ''})[0].get('href')

    # do something meaningful with the scrapped page here
    print(next_url)

    # recur with the newly obtained next page's url
    find_pages(base_url + next_url)

find_pages(base_url)
```

The program can be broken down into following parts:

1. Obtaining html code of the page with [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) (it's worth learning urllib, if you're working with BeautifulSoup!)
2. Parsing the page with BS
3. Finding a link that encloses the word 'next'  (see more details in BS's [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/))
4. Doing something with the page if you need (I'm just printing a name of the link)
5. Doing all previous steps, but for the next page until no next pages left

The code tested in Python 3. Happy hacking and learning!

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow them one by one. Or you can grab the links from an index. For example the page: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ contains all the links you will go through if you follow the `next` button. So you can grab them all from this one place.

You have to decide how you can do this best. That usually needs analyzing the link structures and giving it some thoughts.